# Google Charts is changing my data order

Tags: sorting, google-visualization

I am trying to create a simple Google Charts Column Chart using a date string as the X-axis.  When I pass in an ordered hash (or array) for some reason Google Charts re-orders my data based on its own interpretation of how to sort.

Example:

```
[["Dec 27", 206.17], ["28", 411.09], ["29", 411.09], ["30", 411.09], ["31", 411.09], ["Jan  1", 411.09], [" 2", 411.09], [" 3", 411.09], [" 4", 411.09], [" 5", 411.09], [" 6", 411.09], [" 7", 411.09]]
```

Given this data, Google chart displays:

[X-Axis example as displayed by google charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xjYq.png)

Has anyone else run into and solved this?  Is there a way to tell Google Charts to accept my data order without re-sorting?

Comment: *What* interpretation? Is it ordering lexicographically?

Comment: I think it will sort your strings alphabetically.  If you insist on strings use yyyy-mm-dd, will always sort right.  By the way, there's no guarantee ever of the order of the keys on an object in JavaScript.  The standard is quite specific about that. Best thing in your case is to use a date instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could share all the code, here the column chart keeps the sort the same as defined in the array.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Date", "Amount"],
    ["Dec 27", 206.17],
    ["28", 411.09],
    ["29", 411.09],
    ["30", 411.09],
    ["31", 411.09],
    ["Jan  1", 411.09],
    [" 2", 411.09],
    [" 3", 411.09],
    [" 4", 411.09],
    [" 5", 411.09],
    [" 6", 411.09],
    [" 7", 411.09]
  ]);
  
  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: am I missing something here?